# Primary key detection

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have imported the data into an database.

Patient(pt_id,pt_name,pt_type,pt_loc)

Now , I want to find which of these a primary (have unique) values.

Any way I could found is

```
     select count(pt_id) from patient
     select count(distinct pt_id) from patient
```

would return the same value

Any input would be great :)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single-pass method of determining if the column contains only unique values would be:

```
SELECT pt_id, COUNT(pt_id) from patient
GROUP BY pt_id
HAVING COUNT(pt_id) > 1
```

if you get results, it's not unique.  You may also want to check for nulls:

```
SELECT * from patient
WHERE pt_id is NULL
```